# SQL Query DateTime alignment

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a C# Winforms app that connects to either a SQLServer or Access database.

The table has these fields:

```
DateTime  Name  Value
2/17/2014 Ted   5.5
2/17/2014 Fred  8.2
2/18/2014 Fred  8.3
2/19/2014 Ted   5.3
2/19/2014 Fred  8.1
```

How can I build an SQL statement so that so there is alignment on the DateTime field and the results look like this:

```
DateTime    Ted    Fred
2/17/2014   5.5    8.2
2/18/2014   null   8.3
2/19/2014   5.3    8.1
```

Thanks!

Comment: please show your code in regards to what you have / what you have tired..
also I would do some googling on how to connect / setup connection strings in C# [C# ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) ||
[SQL Basics Tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm)

Comment: You can get your result in sql with the pivot command. But not in Access. You will need to write code to format/process the output to whatever you like.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the T-SQL (SQL Server) native `PIVOT` operator:

```
SELECT "DateTime", "Ted", "Fred"
FROM 
(
  SELECT "DateTime", "name", "value" 
  FROM tbl
) AS D 
PIVOT(MAX("value") FOR "name" IN ("Ted", "Fred")) AS P;
```

You can also do it without using `PIVOT` i.e. by using only standard SQL syntax. Here is how:

```
SELECT "DateTime",
MAX(CASE WHEN "name" = 'Ted' THEN "value" END) AS "Ted",
MAX(CASE WHEN "name" = 'Fred' THEN "value" END) AS "Fred"
FROM tbl
GROUP BY "DateTime";
```

You can find [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bcb8/9) here.